# Speed Queen washing machine making loud popping noise during agitation

Tags: washing-machine

I have a 2013 Speed Queen top load agitator washing that has started to make a loud popping sound during the agitation cycle only.  The washer fills fine, agitates normally, drains and spins on all cycles, it just started making this load popping/clunking noise off and on with the agitation cycle about 1 week ago.  Model # is AWN432SP111TW01.

Comment: What is the frequency of the popping noise?

Comment: The noise happens every agitation cycle, but the popping/clicking noise is not consistent - sometimes it happens only a few times during a cycle, others a handful - it does not seem to have a rhythm to it.